# Common collection view for all tabs in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

In my app, I am using a Tab Bar controller to switch between different views and on each view I have a horizontal collection view.Can anyone explain how to use a common collection view for all tabs so that every tabs in the tab bar controller uses the same horizontal collection view.I've tried it by adding collection view to the tab bar controller storyboard but it didn't work.Is there any way programmatically or non programmatically?

Comment: Post more detail code?

Comment: A UITabBarController is a container which contains 0 to several view controllers. You need to add the collectionview to the view controllers within your tab bar controller, not to the tab bar controller itself. If you are repeating the same collectionview, consider creating a base view controller which all your view controllers can inherit from. Please review: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller